# ngx-translate: language build path wrong

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, jhipster, ngx-translate

I recently updated all my dependencies (yarn upgrade --latest).

For translation I use @ngx-translate. Now, when I build my project (yarn run webpack:build) it adds the language files to the wrong folder and I get a 404 and therefore no translations.

The desired structure should be: `/target/www/i18n/de.json`

The current folder structure is: `/target/www/target/www/i18n/de.json`

Now my guess: There's apparently an error when setting the path (additional ./ or something like that).

My question is: Where can I set the path where to put the compiled language in?

My package.json looks like this (jus the dependencies part):

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.12",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "cryptocoins-icons": "^2.5.0",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ng-jhipster": "0.2.12",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.7.0",
    "ng2-nvd3": "^2.0.0",
    "ng2-webstorage": "1.8.0",
    "ngx-cookie": "1.0.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "0.6.1",
    "ngx-ui-switch": "^1.4.4",
    "nouislider": "^10.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sockjs-client": "1.1.4",
    "swagger-ui": "3.4.2",
    "tether": "1.4.0",
    "webstomp-client": "1.2.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.6.2",
    "@types/node": "8.0.47",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.3.0",
    "browser-sync": "2.18.13",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "1.2.0",
    "codelyzer": "3.2.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.2.0",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "del": "3.0.0",
    "event-stream": "3.3.4",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.5",
    "generator-jhipster": "4.10.2",
    "html-loader": "0.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.30.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "1.1.1",
    "karma-intl-shim": "1.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "1.2.0",
    "karma-notify-reporter": "1.0.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.4",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.6.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.5",
    "lazypipe": "1.0.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "map-stream": "0.0.7",
    "merge-jsons-webpack-plugin": "1.0.12",
    "node-sass": "4.5.3",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.15",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
    "proxy-middleware": "0.15.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.2",
    "run-sequence": "2.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "sourcemap-istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "0.2.0",
    "string-replace-webpack-plugin": "0.1.3",
    "style-loader": "0.19.0",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "tslint": "5.8.0",
    "tslint-loader": "3.5.3",
    "typescript": "2.3.4",
    "web-app-manifest-loader": "0.1.1",
    "webpack": "3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.9.3",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "webpack-notifier": "1.5.0",
    "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "0.1.11",
    "write-file-webpack-plugin": "4.2.0",
    "xml2js": "0.4.19",
    "yargs": "10.0.3"
  },
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-ng2/blob/702ae6e473587e96dc24f54c32b9159865255a92/webpack/webpack.common.js#L105-L113

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks for the hin! :)
However, I haven't changed anything in this file, nor have I upgraded webpack. Any idea where that mismatch in pathes could come from? The strange thing is: the pattern-path works as expected, but only the "fileName" path doesn't for some reason...

Comment: Okey, I googled for hours for any bug but found nothing... In the end I found the solution, which is embarrasingly easy: I changed the "fileName" property to begin with "../.." and then it works :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for anyone who stumbles upon the same problem:
After hours of googling I didn't find the reason for that change. However, I was able to solve it by changing the following lines in **webpack.common.js**:

```
    new MergeJsonWebpackPlugin({
        output: {
            groupBy: [
                { pattern: "./src/main/webapp/i18n/en/*.json", fileName: "./i18n/en.json" },
                { pattern: "./src/main/webapp/i18n/fr/*.json", fileName: "./i18n/fr.json" }
                // jhipster-needle-i18n-language-webpack - JHipster will add/remove languages in this array
            ]
        }
    }),
```

to:

```
    new MergeJsonWebpackPlugin({
        output: {
            groupBy: [
                { pattern: "./src/main/webapp/i18n/en/*.json", fileName: "../../i18n/en.json" },
                { pattern: "./src/main/webapp/i18n/fr/*.json", fileName: "../../i18n/fr.json" }
                // jhipster-needle-i18n-language-webpack - JHipster will add/remove languages in this array
            ]
        }
    }),
```

(Please note the path in **fileName**).

Hope I can save someone the struggle I had with searching for the bug ;)

Answer (score 2):

First off, I don't see any `@ngx-translate` packages installed in your `package.json`

Here's how I'd fix it:

1. `yarn install` both `@ngx-translate/core` and
   `@ngx-translate/http-loader`
2. Then you'll need to define an `HttpLoaderFactory` method. For the sake of getting started, put it in your root module (probably named `app.module.ts`). Remember to first import the modules you just installed:

`import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';`

Then you can can edit the location of your translation files.

`export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: Http) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(
    http, 
    '../target/www/i18n/', // or whatever path you're using
    '.json'
  );
}`

That should get you started. The readme has some helpful examples if you get stuck... https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, in my project there’s everything already set up. Its right that there’s no ngx-translate in my package.json, because that’s coming over a dependency of jhipster (should have mentioned that, sorry). Do you have any other idea what could be wrong? It has been working before I updated my dependencies.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your HttpLoader, as that's where the path will be specified...

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for it. As i understand you are using jhipster.This snippet is tested in jhipster. Just include this code in `app.module.ts`( it shouldn't stay in the `app.module.ts`). This is supposedly an optimization in `ng-jhispter`.

```
import {HttpClientModule, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '/app/i18n/');
}

NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [
        ...
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
    ],

    // The component that loads
        bootstrap: [AppMainComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```