# Jhipster with web context resolve i18n resource with wrong url

Tags: webpack, internationalization, jhipster

I have developed a site using Jhipster, for customer need - **in production** - it must be deployed using a web context different from `/` , e.g. `/CustomerPortal`. Setting for Spring `servlet context` and for Angular **webpack.prod.js** `BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({ baseHref: '/CustomerPortal' })`, all work well.

**Only the URLs for i18n files are wrong.**

In the Jhipster github I found an old issue related to this problem, where someone suggest to modify webpack scripts **webpack.common.js**, in this way:

```
 new MergeJsonWebpackPlugin({
        output: {
            groupBy: [
                { pattern: './src/main/webapp/i18n/en/*.json', fileName: './i18n/en.json' },
                { pattern: './src/main/webapp/i18n/en/*.json', fileName: './CustomerPortal/i18n/en.json' },
                { pattern: './src/main/webapp/i18n/it/*.json', fileName: './i18n/it.json' },
                { pattern: './src/main/webapp/i18n/it/*.json', fileName: './CustomerPortal/i18n/it.json' }
                // jhipster-needle-i18n-language-webpack - JHipster will add/remove languages in this array
            ]
        }
    })
```

I follow this suggestion, but it dosen't work for me, when I inspect chrome **I always see error 404 (not found) for i18n** files because the base context in the requests is omitted. The request url is always `http://my.base.portal/i18n/en.json` instead of the expected `http://my.base.portal/CustomerPortal/i18n/en.json`.

Any suggestion to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT NOTE:**

> With this settings if I call directly in the browser the resource url
> `http://my.base.portal/CustomerPortal/i18n/it.json` I can see the
> downloaded (and correctly) json. So the problem is only about the URL
> composition from the angular client (the resource is present in the
> back-end).

Comment: webpack.common.js does no longer exist since JHipster uses Angular CLI for webpack builds, so I suppose you're using an old version of JHipster, right? Also I'm not sure why you double the patterns, have you tried with only the ones that map to CustomerPortal?

Comment: Hi Gaël, the project was generated about a year ago, so can be that this problem does not exist now in the last Jhipster generated app. I tried also to put only the two lines I need for en|it language translation with my context prefix `...fileName: './CustomerPortal/`. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Why not posting your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**
[Following this tips worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52087547/3311039) I modify the suggestion, with (in `core.module.ts`):

```
declare let process: any;
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const i18nRoute = env === 'production' || env === 'prod' ? '/CustomerPortal/i18n/' : '/i18n/';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient): TranslateHttpLoader 
   {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, i18nRoute);
}
```